# Qt Android SQLite: No such table

Tags: android, sqlite, qt

Creating an test app only with 2 buttons to check sqlite database on android.
Database added on proj files.

Button db connect

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
QSqlDatabase db;
QString dbName = "test.db";
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(dbName);
if(!db.open())
    ui->textEdit_2->setText("no");
else  
ui->textEdit_2->setText("yea");
}
```

Button for test

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QSqlQuery test;
    test.exec("SELECT idcriterion,name FROM criterion");
    //qDebug() << test.lastError().text() << "num " << test.lastError().number();
    ui->textEdit->setText(test.lastError().text());
    while (test.next())
    {
    QString id = test.value(0).toString();
    QString name = test.value(1).toString();
    ui->textEdit->insertPlainText(id+" "+name+"\n");
    }
}
```

Its working perfect on Desktop but Android build take an exept on second button:

> no such table:criterion Unable to execute statement

though database connect "yea"

Android:
SDK: 4.0
NDK: 21.3.6528147
JDK: 1.8
SDK tools: 29
Emulator Android 10

in .pro file

```
android: {
    deployment.path = /assets
    deployment.files = test.db
    INSTALLS += deployment
}
```

Comment: So are you sure your database contains this table? Are you sure 'test.db' opens the correct one in the path you expect?

Comment: Yes i am sure, cos it worked on desktop, its problem on android implementation

Comment: Again: Please make sure the database exists in the current location since you only provide a relative path which depends on the current working directory. Check e.g. with QFile::exists() and use a proper location (e.g. through QStandardPaths)

Comment: You could have had the sqlite create a brand new database in this location. If you tell it to open a sqlite database that does not exist it will create a new one for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its problem on incorrect database path for Android.

If initialized directly "test.db", SQLite driver creates a new empty db file with this name, cos cant find it on android directory.

Right variant for 1st button:

```
QString dbFile = "test.db";
QString emptyFile = "assets:/" + dbFile;
QFile dfile( dbFile ), originalFile( emptyFile );
if ( !dfile.exists() )
{
    originalFile.copy("./test.db");
    QFile::setPermissions("./test.db", QFile::WriteOwner | QFile::ReadOwner );
}
if( QFile::exists( dbFile ) )
{
    QSqlDatabase db;
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName( dbFile );
    if(!db.open())
        ui->textEdit_2->setText(db.lastError().text());
}
```